# Filter Queries For Elasticsearch from Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I would like to use a query filtering these parameters in logstash's elasticsearch input>

```
**host.raw = host 1 OR host 2
&
code != "123"**
```

How could I do the query? I have been trying several things for a while without success
ES version is 1.7.1

```
input{
elasticsearch {
        host=>
        query => '{ "query": .... }'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "host.raw": "host 1"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "host.raw": "host 2"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": {
        "term": {
          "code": "123"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Setting the above query into your config would yield this:

```
input{
   elasticsearch {
       host => "..."
       query => '{"query": {"bool":{"should":[{"term":{"host.raw":"host 1"}},{"term":{"host.raw":"host 2"}}], "must_not":{"term":{"code":"123"}}}}}'
```